# android: ViewPager Indicator like Tinders pictures

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

So, I have a `ViewPager` and I want to realize a simple `Page-Indicator` like Tinder does with its pics:

[image]

[image]

I thought it would be easy to find a library, but for the life of me, I can't find any.

I don't care if the bar is realized by manipulating the width of a dot or with a drawable, the only thing the library should do is **stretching the bars**, so that they always take 100% of the width of the `ViewPager`.

Anyone know a library like that, or is it easy to realize this without help of a  library?

Comment: None of [these libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/111?sort=created) have what you want?

Comment: Apperantly not. I hope that I overlooked a fitting library, it really only needs to fill the viewport on its own.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's solve this problem step by step.

**First, Add Jake Wharton's ViewPager Library in your project. Go to your build.gradle (Module:app) and add this line and sync your project.**

```
implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
```

**Second, Add LinePageIndicator in your xml file where your viewPager is.**

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:strokeWidth="4dp"
        app:unselectedColor="#FF888888"
        app:selectedColor="#FF880000"/>
```

**Third and final step, after attaching a adapter to your viewpager, add this code to get your desired output.**

```
LinePageIndicator linePageIndicator = view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    linePageIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);

    //As we are measuring screen width, you should put the calculation inside onGlobalLayoutListener to get the correct screen width
    linePageIndicator.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int numberOfItems = viewPager.getChildCount();
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            float widthPixel = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

            float itemWidth = widthPixel/numberOfItems;
            linePageIndicator.setLineWidth(itemWidth);
        }
    });
```

And that's it, you've got a full screen wide lineindicator.

Comment: Jo, holy shit, thanks for the elaborate answer. I already see a problem there though, that we are using the width of the display and not of the `viewPager`, but since we are waiting for it to be drawn, thats just a minor change. I will test it in a moment and then accept the answer. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Is there any workaround for Viewpager2?